# How to run multiple task at the same time safely?

Tags: objective-c

I'm developing a iPhone app and I'm relatively new to objective-c so I hope some one can give a clue.

What im doing is reading a file in chunks and encoding the chuncks into base64 and everything is working fine, the problem is that in this line  NSString *str = [data base64EncodedString]; it takes a little bit of time because im encodeing chunks of 256KB, there is no problem with one file the problem is that i'm encoding image files so imagine that I encode 10 images it will be alot of chunks per image so the process can  be slow.

this is the process:
*Get the file.
*Read chunck of 256KB of the file.
*Encode chunck to base64.
*Save the encoded chunck and repeat until there is no more bytes to read from the file.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
 {

     NSUInteger chunkSize =262144;
     uint8_t *buffer = calloc(chunkSize, sizeof(*buffer));
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
     NSUInteger length = [rep size];

     self.requestsToServer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     NSUInteger offset = 0;
     do {
         NSUInteger bytesCopied = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:chunkSize error:nil];
         offset += bytesCopied;

         NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:bytesCopied];

         NSString *str = [data base64EncodedString];

         //After this I add the str in a  NSMutableURLRequest and I store the request
          //in a  NSMutableArray for later use.

      } while (offset < length);
     free(buffer);
     buffer = NULL;
}
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {

 }];
```

I want to  start another thread so I can be encoding the chuncks in paralel and know when the process finish, this way while encoding one chunck I can be encodign another 3 or 4 chunks at the same time.

How I can implement this in a safely way or is this a good idea?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Simply create one NSOperation per chunk and pass them the chunk they need to encode and queue them up.

You can tell the queue how many operations can run simultaneously.

Comment: If everything is already running inside a GCD, should anyway apply NSOperation and NSOperationQueue?

Comment: NSOperationQueue is implemented using GCD. It's a high level wrapper around GCD since GCD was published. You still need to spread the load on other threads to have a fluid UI which processing data. You can do it using GCD but is more of an headache unless you want something that NSOperationQueue does not support.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good options for doing chunks of work in parallel for iOS.

Take a look at the Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get you going.